# I am not able to get proper tab image/thumbnail using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am very new to HTML 5 and truing to use canvas elements for the image. now scenario is i am using tab selection structure in that if user click on tab thumbnail image (which is in slider) at that time that tab should open. now thing is that i am trying to make thumbnail dynamically and not able to get proper thumbnail. in thumbnail contain part comes properly but images/video is not displaying in thumbnail....

I hope you understand the problem I face... still for your convince I am uploading Image here..

[image]

Comment: html2canvas(document.getElementById('tab1'),{
     
onrendered: function (canvas) {
var d = document.getElementById("tab1");
d.className = d.className + "tab";
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image');
var image = new Image();
image.src = data;
      document.getElementById('tab1thum').appendChild(image);
      
     }
    });

Comment: Your image/video will not be rendered onto canvas if they don't originate on the same domain as your webpage.  See this warning from html2canvas: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html

Comment: @markE Is there any other way to achieve what i want? by php

Answer (score 0):

I see in your comment that you're open to using PHP.

Check out PhantomJS which is a WebKit browser that runs in PHP.

It is "headless" == it doesn't draw output to any screen.

It has many purposes, but for your purposes you can feed PhantomJS some html and it can render it to an image file.

Here's a link:

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply @markE. we want to only some html portion that contains text, links, images, video. that portion convert into image.

Comment: If you want only a portion of the pages' html to render you'll have to filter just that portion of html--jquery could help with that.